# Correct place to register and enqueue scripts

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, actions

I'm queueing several scripts in my themes Functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists('b99_init_scripts') ) :
    function b99_init_scripts(){

        if ( !is_admin()){
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, null, false);
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('B99', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascript/site/B99.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
            wp_enqueue_script('B99');

        wp_register_script('B99-Nav', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascript/site/module/B99.Navigation.js', array('B99'), null, false );
        wp_enqueue_script('B99-Nav');

            if ( is_page('portfolio') || is_front_page() ){
                wp_register_script('B99-Portfolio', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascript/site/module/B99.Portfolio.js', array('B99-Nav'), null, false);
                wp_enqueue_script('B99-Portfolio');
            } // fails if add_action is set to 'init'

            if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ){
                wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
            }
        }
    }
    endif;
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b99_init_scripts' );
```

I have read that the proper place to add_action is to 'init'

```
add_action( 'init', 'b99_init_scripts' );
```

However, my `is_page('xxx')` checks all fail during init.

Coded as I have pasted above:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'b99_init_scripts' );
```

works as expected and the page checks work normally, but I don't think I should be deregistering, registering, and enqueueing during the wp_enqueue_scripts routine.

Is there a better location to hook into, or can I alter my page check during init to function correctly  (I assume the page check doesn't work because the needed queries haven't fired yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function named `b99_register_scripts()` and hook this into `init`. Then you can create another function named `b99_enqueue_scripts()` and hook it into `wp_print_scripts`.

Comment: That seems quite reasonable, and correct solution for the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is fine if it works for you. or `wp_print_scripts` is also an option.

the point of `wp_register_script` is so you can register something anywhere in your code if you have multiple potential dependencies, and then just enqueue once in the proper location. if you're doing it all in one place you can just skip registering it and just enqueue it straight away, the results will be the same.

Comment: Right. And currently - they are registered an queued in the same spot, but that may change... thanks for the info. Will check out wp_print_scripts.